# Azure not stopping VM

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I've created a VM on Azure and I'm trying to stop it. I clicked the stop button in the Azure Portal and I got a message saying "Stopping Virtual Machine" this has been going on for the last 30 minutes. Is it normal for Azure to take this long to stop a VM or is there something wrong here?

Comment: Can you use PowerShell to get the VM's status?

Comment: Please use this command to show the status, `Get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName xxx -Name xxxx -Status`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, maybe there are something wrong with the browse, we can use PowerShell to get the status of your Azure VM, in this way we can find the VM's status:

```
PS C:\Users> Get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName vm -Name jasonvm -Status
ResourceGroupName          : vm
Name                       : jasonvm
BootDiagnostics            :
  ConsoleScreenshotBlobUri : https://vmdiag136.blob.core.windows.net/bootdiagnostics-jasonvm-fd5e4f46-55c0-4b6e-9640-a66a175c6f02/jasonvm.fd5e4f46-55c0-4b6e-9640-a66a175c6f02.screenshot.bmp
  SerialConsoleLogBlobUri  : https://vmdiag136.blob.core.windows.net/bootdiagnostics-jasonvm-fd5e4f46-55c0-4b6e-9640-a66a175c6f02/jasonvm.fd5e4f46-55c0-4b6e-9640-a66a175c6f02.serialconsole.log
Disks[0]                   :
  Name                     : jasonvm
  Statuses[0]              :
    Code                   : ProvisioningState/succeeded
    Level                  : Info
    DisplayStatus          : Provisioning succeeded
    Time                   : 5/16/2017 9:45:28 AM
VMAgent                    :
  VmAgentVersion           : 2.2.10
  Statuses[0]              :
    Code                   : ProvisioningState/succeeded
    Level                  : Info
    DisplayStatus          : Ready
    Message                : Guest Agent is running
    Time                   : 5/16/2017 9:51:35 AM
Statuses[0]                :
  Code                     : ProvisioningState/succeeded
  Level                    : Info
  DisplayStatus            : Provisioning succeeded
  Time                     : 5/16/2017 9:47:41 AM
Statuses[1]                :
  Code                     : PowerState/running
  Level                    : Info
  DisplayStatus            : VM running
```

Also we can use PowerShell command to **stop** this VM:
`Stop-AzureRmVM -Name -ResourceGroupName`

For test, we can change **another browse** to login Azure portal.

Comment: I used the Powershell to stop the VM. Thanks for your help :)